# Two condition true in specific period

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, multiple-conditions

I want to write an indicator on tradingview solve one pine script problem. I have three indicators (for example MACD, EMA14 and volume) and I want to check these indicators for specific period. If in two periods ta.crossover(macdLine, macdSignal) and close>ema14 and volume>volumeavg14 has to be true. How can I make it. Could you explain to me?

Conditions can be true different bars and different order. Important thing is all conditions have to be true in specific period.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by period?

Comment: Period means bar. for example 2 bars or 3 bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ta.barssince()` function to detect how long it has been since a condition was `true`. This way, you can define your periods.

Below example shows a three bar period (marked by *X*s) when the price crosses over EMA14.

You would do the same for your other conditions and finally **and** them together.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ema_14 = ta.ema(close, 14)
ema_cross = ta.crossover(close, ema_14)
bs_ema_cross = ta.barssince(ema_cross)

ema_cond = ema_cross or ((bs_ema_cross > 0) and (bs_ema_cross < 3))

plot(ema_14)
plotshape(ema_cond)
```

[image]